# Read a tuple from a file in Scala

Tags: scala

my Task is to read registrations from a file given like:

```
Keri,345246,2
Ingar,488058,2
Almeta,422016,1
```

and insert them into a list(Tuple of (String, Int, Int).

So far I wrote this:
[image]

The problem is that I don‘t understand why I can't try to cast value2 and value3 to Int even tho they should be Strings because they come from an Array of Strings. Could someone tell me, what my mistake is, I am relatively new to Scala

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't post code as image: it cannot be copy/pasted and it's harder to read in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

What is the point of using **Scala** if you are going to write **Java** code?

This is how you would properly read a file as a `List` of case classes.

```scala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Using

// Use proper names for the fields.
final case class Registration(field1: String, field2: Int, field3: Int)

// You may change the error handling logic.
def readRegistrationsFromFile(fileName: String): List[Registration] =
  Using(Source.fromFile(fileName)) { source =>
    source.getLines().map(line => line.split(',').toList).flatMap {
      case field1Raw :: field2Raw :: field3Raw :: Nil =>
        for {
          field2 <- field2Raw.toIntOption
          field3 <- field3Raw.toIntOption
        } yield Registration(field1 = field1Raw.trim, field2, field3)

      case _ =>
        None
    }.toList
  }.getOrElse(default = List.empty)
```

*(feel free to ask any question you may have about this code)*

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, in order to convert a `String` to an `Int` you need explicit casting.

This can be achieved like this if you are sure the string can be parsed into a integer:

```scala
val values = values(1).toInt
```

If you cannot trust the input (and you probably should not), you can use `.toIntOption` which will give you a `Option[Int]` defined if the value was converted successfully or undefined if the string did not represent an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are correct. I would add a few more points.

1. `saveContent` is declared as a `val`. This is means it cannot be changed (assigned another value). You can use the Scala REPL (command-line) tool to check:

```
scala> val saveContent = Nil
val v: collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()

scala> saveContent = 3
         ^
       error: reassignment to val
```

Instead, you could use a `var`, although it would be more idiomatic to have an overall pattern like the one provided by Luis Miguel's answer - with [pattern-matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) and a for-comprehension.

2. You can use the Scala REPL to check the types of the variables, too. Splitting a String will always lead to more Strings, not Ints, etc.

```
> val values = "a,2,3".split(",")
val values: Array[String] = Array(a, 2, 3)

> values(2)
val res3: String = 3
```

This is why a cast like Gael's is necessary.

3. Array-type access is done with parentheses and not square brackets, in Scala. See above, and http://scalatutorials.com/tour/interactive_tour_of_scala_lists for more details.